# Como puedo recorrer los dos arrays para que el precio aparezca seguido del producto? Java

Tags: java

```
 public static void main(String... santiago) {
   
    //Pedir productos al cliente
    String[] productos = new String[3];
    int[] precios = new int[3];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("INGRESE PRODUCTOS");
        productos[i] = sc.next();
        System.out.println("INGRESE PRECIO");
        precios[i] = sc.nextInt();
        
        
    
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i < productos.length ; i++){
    for(String valorP : productos){
        
        for(int valorC : precios){
            System.out.println(valorP);
            System.out.println(valorC);
        }
    }
    
    }
    
    
    
    
     
     
     
     
    
}
```

Estoy creando 2 arrays y delimitandolos para que contengan 3 valores que los estoy asignando por pantalla. Al ya tenerlos asignado quiero que se recorran los dos y que aparezca el precio abajo del producto pero al poner dos for para recorrer los dos aparecen 6 veces claro por que recorro uno de 3 y luego otro pero como podria hacer para recorrer los dos al mismo tiempo en el for y solo aparezca 3 veces como la cantidad de valores que hay, creo que esa seria la mejor opcion para hacerlo no ?
Como puedo recorrer los dos arrays para que el precio aparezca seguido del producto?

Agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Quieres recorrer dos array y usas tres loops? No te parece que algo no encaja?? De todas maneras, dado que ambos array son idénticos en longitud, no necesitas recorrerlos individualmente... con el primer `for (int i=0;i < productos.length...` te sobra, puesto que ambos tienen la misma longitud, siempre vas a poder acceder a `productos[i]` y `precios[i]` sin errores. Poner código al azar sin intentar pensar en qué necesitas y qué estás haciendo no suele dar resultado. Al menos no el resultado esperado. Coge una hoja de papel, anota lo que imprimes en cada iteración de tu código y cómo cambiarlo

Comment: Hola Santiago, bienvenido, tu confusión, se debe a que quieres usar "forEach", pero cuando necesitas datos de dos "array's" debes usar el "for" ya que te "provee" de la necesaria variable "i" para pedir los datos de ambos "array's", por otro lado, para que queden seguidos, puedes usar **System.out.println( productos[ i ] + " " + precios[ i ] );**

Answer (score 0):

la solución ya la tienes y la has resuelto tu mismo!
Al inicio de tu código tienes lo siguiente:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("INGRESE PRODUCTOS");
    productos[i] = sc.next();
    System.out.println("INGRESE PRECIO");
    precios[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Si te das cuenta utilizas unicamente un ciclo for para pedir el producto y justo debajo pides el precio, porque no hacer lo mismo para mostrar los datos? algo así:

```
for (int i = 0; i < productos.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Producto: " + productos[i]);
    System.out.println("Precio: " + precios[i]);
}
```

De esa forma usas un solo ciclo para pedir los datos y un solo ciclo para mostrarlos de la misma forma.

Aquí el código completo:

```
public static void main(String... santiago) {

    //Pedir productos al cliente
    String[] productos = new String[3];
    int[] precios = new int[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("INGRESE PRODUCTOS");
        productos[i] = sc.next();
        System.out.println("INGRESE PRECIO");
        precios[i] = sc.nextInt();

    }

    System.out.println("Productos registrados");

    for (int i = 0; i < productos.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Producto: " + productos[i]);
        System.out.println("Precio: " + precios[i]);
    }
}
```